# jquery append to append not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my problem is after append element my select options for append more not work .
first i append some spans ( in 2 div ) and its work , but after i add another div with Append my old append not added in new append div ! (hope you guys understand what i say :P and sorry for my bad eng )
please check my code.

```js
if ($('.returnRequests').length) {
        var count = 1;
        function emptyRow() {
            this.obj = $('<span class="returnRequests"></span>');
            this.obj.append('<input placeholder="input '+ (count++) +'" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3 p-0 pr-2 mr-2 d-inline-block" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="60" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" type="text">\n');
        }

        function refresh(count) {

            var wrapper = $('#productRowWrappers');
            while (wrapper.children().length > count)
                wrapper.children().last().remove();

            while (wrapper.children().length < count)
                wrapper.append((new emptyRow()).obj);
        }

        $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {
            refresh(parseInt($(this).val()));
        });
    }

    function addhotel() {

        $('.add-hotel').append(`
    <div class="hotels-dashboard hotel-add-1 container mb-3">
      <p class="mt-2">
        <span class="title-main"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i> Hotels </span>
        <span onclick="addhotel()" id="add-hotel" class="float-left bg-add-hotel p-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> AddMore  </span>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="row container ">
        <div class="returnRequests col-md-12 p-0" id="productRowWrappers"></div>
      </div>
     <!-- EXTRA DIV HERE, BREAKS YOUR HTML CODE -->
            `
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select col-md-4 mt-2 mb-2 mb-sm-0" id="quantityReturn" >
    <option value="0" selected> select number </option>
    <option  value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option  value="4">4</option>
</select>


<div class="add-hotel">

    <div class="hotels-dashboard hotel-add-1 container mb-3">

        <p class="mt-2">
            <span class="title-main"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i> Hotels </span>
            <span onclick="addhotel()" id="add-hotel" class="float-left bg-add-hotel p-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> AddMore   </span>
        </p>
        <hr>

        <div class="row container ">

            <div class="returnRequests col-md-12 p-0" id="productRowWrappers">


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Multi-line strings might not be available in your environment. They're an es6 feature. Try putting `div.hotels-dashboard` all on one line.

Comment: Also, maybe go with single-quotes when using html in strings in js (that'll save you having to ` \ ` escape the double quotes). There's a lot that can go wrong with a string that long.

Comment: Plus: if you use `'\n'` (simple quotes), this is not a return, this is `backslash + n`. You have to make it inside double quotes (`"\n"`) to use a return character. By the way, this is unecessary, in HTML code.

Comment: Plus: `$('<span class="returnRequests"></span>')` means nothing… Use `$('span.returnRequests')` instead.

Comment: thanks for answer guys , but my real problem is when you choice 1 select option you see 1 span added in 2 div , but if you click on add hotel , you see another div append but not append input ( we append it with select option ) . i mean this part .         this.obj.append('<input placeholder="hotel '+ (count++) +'" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3 p-0 pr-2 mr-2 d-inline-block" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="60" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" type="text">\n');

Comment: You want the input fields to be added to *each* hotel? not just the first one? Is it that?

Comment: Yes , i want after i add hotels if i change inputs ( select option ) in all hotels inputs changed like first hotel.

Comment: It's not difficult, several ways, but they depend on what you want precisely. For instance, what about the *value* of the input fields? Should it be 'copied' with the field? Or field have to be empty?

Comment: i want empty fields like first hotels .later this inputs show some data from DB , like city names . input 1 city 1 input 2 city 2 and ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiny working solution:

Do you need some explaination?

I have to proceed some changes on your code so it is more readdable/understandable. Tell me if you want me to point them.

In brief:

- The buttons are outside the hotel divs (only one is needed)
- Use a `div#hotels` as hotel(s) container
- Use a `.hotel` class (simplier and semantical than `hotel-add`)
- Remove the multi-used "productRowWrappers" `id` to use it as a `class`
- Add a label to show the hotel index
- Use a simple function with return for new input field (not a class)
  (the problem was also here)
- Use simplier method to remove and add input fields
  (yours have been doing too much/unecessary work)

```js
function addhotel()
{
  let allHotels = $('#hotels .hotel')
    , newHotel  = allHotels.first().clone()
    , hotelID   = allHotels.length + 1 ;

  // Set the ID attribute to be uniq
  newHotel.attr('id', "hotel-add-" + hotelID) ;
      // "hotel-<ID>" as ID would be better, though

  // We write the hotel index
  newHotel.find('.hotel-number').text(hotelID);
  
  $('#hotels').append( newHotel );

}


if ($('.returnRequests').length) {

  // Return an empty row
  function emptyRow(hotelNum) {
    return '<input placeholder="hotel '+ hotelNum +'" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3 p-0 pr-2 mr-2 d-inline-block" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="60" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" type="text">'
  }
    
  /**  
    * "Refresh" each hotel with the required
    *  count of input fields. Add or remove them as necessary.
    *
    */
  function refresh(count) {

    // Loop on each hotel

    $('#hotels .hotel').each(function(hotelIndex, o){
      
      // How manu fields in place ?
      let fieldsCount = $(o).find('.form-control-sm').length;

      // Just in case…
      if ( fieldsCount == count ) { return ; }
      
      let wrapper = $(o).find('.productRowWrappers');

      // Too much fields or not enough?

      if (fieldsCount > count)
      {

        // To much => remove surplus

        wrapper.find('.form-control-sm:nth-child(n+'+(count+1)+')').remove();
      }
      else
      {

        // Not enough => create the missing

        let i, len, hotelNum = hotelIndex + 1 ;

        for(i = 0, len = count-fieldsCount ; i < len ; ++ i)
        {
          wrapper.append(emptyRow(hotelNum));
        }
      }
    })
    
  }

  $('#quantityReturn').change(function () {
      refresh(parseInt($(this).val()));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select col-md-4 mt-2 mb-2 mb-sm-0" id="quantityReturn">
    <option value="0" selected> select number </option>
    <option  value="1">1</option>
    <option  value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option  value="4">4</option>
</select>

<p class="mt-2">
  <span class="title-main"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i> Hotels </span>
  <button onclick="addhotel()" id="add-hotel-button" class="float-left bg-add-hotel p-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add More</button>
</p>

<!-- ID is better here -->
<div id="hotels">
  
  <div id="hotel-add-1" class="hotel hotels-dashboard container mb-3">
    <hr>
    <div>Hotel #<span class="hotel-number">1</span></div>
    <div class="returnRequests col-md-12 p-0 productRowWrappers">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its best answer and help , really thank you its work great .

Comment: Thanks @ShayanSakha. Could you also upvote the answer so that this answer stays at the top, please.

Answer (score 0):

Help you, @ShayanSakha…

If you try to write a clean code, you help you to find a lot of errors. And you help us to help you.

Look, for instance, the extra `</div>`, here, that breaks your HTML code and may be the reason of your problem. With your (ugly, sorry) code, you're not able to see it (neither us).

*(notice: I remove all of your `\n`. They mean nothing in HTML language. Don't use them)*

```
function addhotel() {

  $('.add-hotel').append(`
    <div class="hotels-dashboard hotel-add-1 container mb-3">
      <p class="mt-2">
        <span class="title-main"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i> Hotels </span>
        <span onclick="addhotel()" id="add-hotel" class="float-left bg-add-hotel p-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add  </span>
        <span id="removehotels"></span>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="row container ">
        <div class="returnRequests col-md-12 p-0" id="productRowWrappers"></div>
        <select class="custom-select col-md-4 mb-2 mt-3 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
          <option selected="">test</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="row price-input">
        <!--
             HERE FOUR TIMES THE SAME ID
             ID MUST BE UNIQ IN THE BODY
          -->
        <input placeholder="test place" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        <input placeholder="test place" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        <input placeholder="test place" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        <input placeholder="test place" class="form-control-sm form-text col-md-3" id="edit-submitted-codepostal" name="submitted[CodePostal]" value="" size="20" autocomplete="off" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="md-form text-area-dashboard col-md-8 mt-4">
        <textarea type="text" id="need-madarek" class="md-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="need-madarek" class="comment-label pr-2">label</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- EXTRA DIV HERE, BREAKS YOUR HTML CODE -->
    `
  )
}
```

But you should never write such a bunch of code…

Tell me if it works better, maybe it's just a first step (remember : *there's always at least two problems in one problem*).

Comment: Thanks for answer , this code work like my ( ugly ) code , but still after append ( .hotels-dashboard ) , this code ( if we append it ) #quantityReturn not show ! Look i want copy .hotels-dashboard and append it with this div #productRowWrappers and if i change select options ( append spans in div#productRowWrappers ) . just click on Hotels add and you see another hotel div appended but value on select option not appended in new div !

Comment: @ShayanSakha, could you, in your answer (edit it), explain *what you want, but without any code*, rather from user point of view. Just: "When an user click the Add button, I want the page to display an new form etc.". I can't understand what you want, with a selectors explanation ;-).

Comment: Thanks for help , i edit my code , Now please run my code ( run code snippet ) you see 1 select box if you select 1 , 1 div append and ... its work good, but now please select 1 option ( 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 ) after span append please Click on text AddMore you see another div appended but i need if i set select option after another div append show values like first div . look first div you change select option input add or remove but after append i want others div ( like first div ) show inputs ... hope you understand it now .

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your `addhotel` function should look like the code below.

I simply:

- use a *clone* of the original form
- change its ID to be uniq
- add it to a `#hotels` container (you have to had it in your code).

Function code:

```
function addhotel()
{

  // Get all the hotels

  let allHotels = $('.hotel') ;

  // Clone the first one

  let newHotel = allHotels.first().clone() ;

  // Set an uniq ID from hotels count

  newHotel.attr('id', "hotel-" + (allHotels.length + 1))

  // Append it to the container

  $('#hotels').append( newHotel );

 }
```

Your HTML code looks like:

```
<div id="hotels"><!-- add this to your code -->

  <div class="hotel" id="hotel-1"><!-- a convenient ID -->

    <!-- ... -->

  </div>
```

After add, it looks like:

```
<div id="hotels">

  <div class="hotel" id="hotel-1">

    <!-- ... -->

  </div>

  <div class="hotel" id="hotel-2"><!-- Notice the uniq ID -->

    <!-- same content -->

  </div>

</div><!-- /#hotels container -->
```

Of course, maybe you have to reset the form. Or hide a model form in your HTML to clone it.

Now we can start to go on.